# is there an alternative to the Angular Material legacy component?

Tags: angular-material

legacy component of angular-material will be eliminated in angular v17, but I would like to continue to use the legacy component in our project instead of the MDC migrated, so is there an alternative to the legacy component?

I'm trying to find out if there are any alternatives to the style of legacy component without using the legacy component, but I can't seem to find anything like that.